# Nice way to group data in a `data.table` when the new column name is given as a character vector

Tags: r, data.table

In other words, my question is about the `j` argument to `data.table` when the name of the new column is a character vector. For example:

```
dt <- data.table(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), y = rnorm(6))
agg_col_name <- 'avg'

grouped_dt <- dt[, .(z = mean(y)), by = x]
setnames(grouped_dt, 'z', agg_col_name)
```

```
> grouped_dt
   x        avg
1: 1 -0.2554987
2: 2 -0.4245852
3: 3 -0.4881073
```

There should be a more elegant way to do the last two statements as one, yes?

Perhaps this is a question about how to create suitable `list` for the `j` argument.

Comment: in the CRAN version no, in the dev version yes it's easier

Comment: https://rdrr.io/github/Rdatatable/data.table/f/vignettes/datatable-programming.Rmd

Comment: In one line although not very elegant: `dt[, setNames(.(mean(y)), agg_col_name), by = x]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although probably not what you are looking for, but you could use `setNames` inside, where it wraps around `(.(z = mean(y))`.

```
library(data.table)

dt[, setNames(.(z = mean(y)), agg_col_name), by = x]
```

Or use `setnames` after doing the summary:

```
setnames(dt[, mean(y), by = x], 'V1', agg_col_name)[]
```

**Output**

```
   x        avg
1: 1  0.5626526
2: 2  0.3549653
3: 3 -0.2861405
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, it is easier to do with the dev version of `data.table`. You can see more about the development of this feature at [programming on data.table #4304]:(https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304).

```
# Latest development version:
data.table::update.dev.pkg()

library(data.table)

dt[, .(z = mean(y)), by = x, env = list(z=agg_col_name)]

#   x        avg
#1: 1 -0.1640783
#2: 2  0.5375794
#3: 3  0.1539785
```

Comment: You don't need get in the last solution: `dt[, .(z = mean(y)), by = x, env = list(z=agg_col_name)]`